# Import/Export BizTalk Health Monitor Profile ( including Settings )

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020, bhm

We use BizTalk Health Monitor (Version 5.0) as additional Monitoring Tool for our BizTalk Environment.
Within BHM we created a Monitoring Profile which fits our needs and we would like to "backup" our Profiles having an export scheduled on a regular basis and moreover be able to import this profile at any time.

I only found a profile settings file under *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\BizTalkHealthMonitor* - Name: MBVSETTINGS_.xml
This looks like the one i would like to "backup".

Unfortunately i was not able to find any "import" functionality which enables me to restore the profile.

Am I missing this feature or does it not exist?
Is there any out of the box functionality to "backup/restore" BHM Profile settings?
Is there any other way to "backup/restore" the profile ( including settings )?

Comment: Have you tried, right click on BizTalk Health Monitor, Import Existing Report

Comment: Unfortunately this only imports the report i specify. But my goal would be to import the complete Monitoring Profile including settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no buit-in export/import profile feature but profiles registration is quite simple: they are stored indeed in .XML files under "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\BizTalkHealthMonitor"

For each profile file you have a sub-folder containing its reports generated. its path is referenced in the "options" tag of the corresponding .XML profile file

To "import" profiles on another box you just need so to copy these .XML profile files and paste them on the same folder of the destination box.

If you prefer, you can also share created BHM profiles on a single box and access them from different BHM boxes. To do that, you just need to update the registry string value "ProfilesPath" in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\BizTalkHealthMonitor\Settings of each box with the UNC path of the profiles share.
You will have them to update the reports folder path of each remote profile by putting its UNC form in the "options" tag of the remote .XML profile file

JP
BHM Author